# TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, babeljs, twitch-api

I'm developing a small twitch connector, and I'm facing a major error:
This is the following error:

```
BasicPubSubClient.js:25
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
                           ^

TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I'm doing the imports as follows:

```js
import {PubSubClient} from 'twitch-pubsub-client';
import {ApiClient} from 'twitch';
import {StaticAuthProvider} from 'twitch-auth';
```

And calling the method:

```js
class pubSubClientHandler {
    constructor() {
    --> this.pubSubClient = new PubSubClient(); <---
        this.authProvider = new StaticAuthProvider(process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID, process.env.TWITCH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        this.apiClient = new ApiClient({ authProvider: this.authProvider });
    }
```

This is my `package.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "starter-express-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/cyclic-software/starter-express-api.git"
  },
  "author": "Pedro Azevedo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/cyclic-software/starter-express-api/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/cyclic-software/starter-express-api#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.8",
    "core-js": "^3.35.1",
    "cron": "^3.1.6",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-ws": "^5.0.2",
    "openai": "^4.20.1",
    "promisify": "^0.0.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "say": "^0.16.0",
    "sound-play": "^1.1.0",
    "tmi.js": "^1.8.5",
    "twitch": "^4.6.7",
    "twitch-auth": "^4.6.7",
    "twitch-pubsub-client": "^4.6.7",
    "ws": "^8.14.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5"
  }
}
```

And my .babelrc

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {"targets": {"esmodules": true}}
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: OK, found the offending source here: https://github.com/twurple/twurple/blob/main/packages/pubsub/src/BasicPubSubClient.ts.  I think this is probably an issue with your Babel settings because the final code is not using modern subclassing because the source is doing `super();`, but the generated code is doing very old fashioned sublcassing that doesn't work with modern classes.

Comment: Interesting. So how should I proceed?
My babel version is 7.23.4 (@babel/core 7.23.7)
And node is 20.11.0
I updated everything to avoid problems on that regard.
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
I also tried this babel settings.

Comment: I don't know much about Babel, but it's settings are apparently wrong and not configured to allow ES6 class syntax to remain in the generated code.